# Ограничения на уведомления от приложения

Tags: flash, iframe, вконтакте

Добрый день!

Есть вопросы по поводу приложения для ВКонтакте (IFrame и flash).
1. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы установленное пользователем приложение отправляло на стену пользователя уведомления без запроса подтверждения пользователя?
2. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы приложение отправляло без подтверждения пользователя личные сообщения друзьям пользователя?
3. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы приложение создавало на стене пользователя опрос?
4. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы приложение отправляло администратору приложения статистику действий пользователя?
5. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы администратор приложения мог запрещать запуск приложения конкретным пользователем?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Можно только на стену пользователя, у приложения должен быть доступ к постингу.
2. Можно, уведомления, через свой сервер (1 сообщение в час).
3. Нельзя.
4. Через общие переменные в vk api с ограничениями, но гораздо лучше через свой сервер.
5. Возможно через общие переменные в vk api с ограничениями, через свой сервер проще.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ.
Не могли бы вы уточнить, с чем связано отсутствие возможности разместить опрос? Это ограничение связано с запретом на подобную активность приложений или с тем, что это технически невозможно?
Возможность создавать опросы и считывать их результаты на прямую связана с функциональностью приложения.

Comment: в vk api нет описания подобного метода - https://vk.com/pages?oid=-17680044&p=API_Method_Description

возможно через свои приложения, на стене вешать картинку/текст и ссылку в попап окно на приложение с опросом/голосованием

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.

Comment: questions.add – creates a new question это, случайно, не нужный мне метод?

Comment: Нет.

Это метод для сервиса "ВОПРОСЫ".
___

Кстати, опросы может создавать standalone приложение  
https://vk.com/dev/polls.create

Answer (score 0):

Иосиф, залогиньтесь

Рекомендую ознакомиться с правилами платформы.

https://vk.com/dev/rules

> 2.1. Запрещается собирать и хранить пользовательские данные, включая
> идентификатор пользователя (User ID),
> в целях, не связанных с
> функционированием приложения.
> Запрашиваемые данные должны
> использоваться только в контексте
> приложения.
>
> 2.2. У приложения должна быть политика конфиденциальности. Если ее нет,
> используется политика
> конфиденциальности ВКонтакте.
>
> 2.3. Запрещается передавать любые пользовательские данные, полученные
> через API (включая User ID), сторонним
> сервисам (например, рекламным) как
> напрямую, так и через посредников.
>
> 2.4. Запрещается использовать пользовательские данные в любых
> рекламных объявлениях.
>
> 4.2. Приложение не должно вызывать какие-либо активные действия в API без
> ведома пользователей и без их
> согласия.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ.

Не понял про "залогиньтесь".

Все уведомления, о которых упомянуто, необходимы для реализации основной функциональности приложения.
Основной вопрос: если при установке приложения предупредить пользователя о том, что приложение будет самостоятельно в дальнейшем отправлять личные сообщения его контактам и оставлять записи на стене, этого достаточно или обязательно, чтобы приложение каждый раз спрашивало разрешение у пользователя?
Эти правила я видел, но они расплывчатые... Намерения спамить с помощью приложения нет.